# PDF Files can't download In Webview In Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview

Please help me,
I make one Flutter app that show website page using webview in my app and this website show list of books pdf file that user can easily download.
Problem is when i touch those pdf file then it should not download.

Here my code ( only some portion):

```
import 'dart:io'; import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart'; 
import 'LoadingIndicator.dart'; 
  
 class Row_Element_2 extends StatefulWidget { 
   final String url; 
  
   const Row_Element_2({ 
     Key? key, 
     required this.url, 
   }) : super(key: key); 
  
   @override 
   State<Row_Element_2> createState() => _Row_Element_2State(this.url); 
 } 
  
 class _Row_Element_2State extends State<Row_Element_2> { 
   final String url; 
   _Row_Element_2State(this.url); 
  
   //for indicatroe (Loader) 
   bool isLoading = true; 
   final _key = UniqueKey(); 
  
   @override 
   void initState() { 
     super.initState(); 
  
     if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView(); 
   } 
  
   @override 
   Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
     return SafeArea( 
       child: Stack( 
         children: [ 
           WebView( 
             key: _key, 
             initialUrl: this.url, 
             javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted, 
             onPageFinished: (finish) { 
               setState(() { 
                 isLoading = false; 
               }); 
             }, 
           ), 
           isLoading ? Container(child: LoadingIndicator()) : Stack(), 
         ], 
       ), 
     ); 
   } 
 }
```

Here url are come from other page.

Webview Page in my app:

When i tap any of this book then it not should be downloaded.

[image]

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf document.

Comment: `when i touch those pdf file then it should not download.` Ok but what should happen instead?

Comment: `When i tap any of this book then it not should be downloaded.` ? Book? I see no book. And if not download what instead?

Comment: @blackapps  When we touch link show in box then book pdf download. But when i tap that nothing is happening,just i tap and no changes.  Official website: https://www.pdfdrive.com/nptel-books.html

Comment: @blackapps  So, what i use for download file in webview in flutter?